# How to practice HAML and SASS (environment)

Tags: haml, development-environment, sass

Could you please give me advice how its better to practice HAML and SASS.

I`ve downloaded and installed everything for windows and i can compile files and use it via command line. But still i want to be able to code and browse it at once, not writing anything in command line.

I mean what shall i do on my localhost to use it? Am i to use with any kind of engine, Drupal for example. Or is there a more simple way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by browse it at once without writing anything in the command line ?
Did you try using the --watch flag ? So that Sass/Compass will watch the .sass files for change and recompile the .css each time.

Comment: Its ok with Sass. But could i do the same with HAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, for Sass and Compass, you can always use the --watch flag to watch the modified files and recompile them on the go.
Now I reckon this doesn't account for HAML wich doesn't have a --watch flag, or other languages such as CoffeeScript etc. The best solution for the moment for a stable and easy to work with environment is to use an external software that will do the command line work for you.

There are several out there, I've tried out a few of them — depending on your current platform and how much you want to put in (from 0$ to 9$). I don't know a lot of free preprocessors manager so if people want to go and comment with free alternatives I'd be glad.

The best *in my humble opinion* is [LiveReload](http://livereload.com) because it's what I've tested to be the most permissive in your organization, it compiles fast, reloads your browser on change, etc.
Cons are it's best to use it on a Mac, considering the Windows version is still in beta and far from finished. But if you're on a Mac, to me it's definitely the way to go.

You can use [FireApp](http://fireapp.handlino.com) too, it does the same job but it's a little less permissive. There are things you can't do with your Compass configuration files, folders you have to name a certain way, etc. It's also paying, but it's cross-plateform (coded in JRuby).

On the free side of life, you currently have [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) for Mac but it's free only during the beta and will become paying. On the other hand it's really worth it's money for how well executed it is and it will really make your life simpler.

You can probably go look on the internet for similar softwares, but you get the idea. Currently the best way to have an easy to use work environment while avoiding the command line is to go through those kinds of softwares.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I may have to mention that [Zen Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) has a nice filter for HAML.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently discovered a free online SASS/SCSS-HAML editor, named Voyage, developed by Zhi-Qiang Lei (thanks!). Very useful for beginners to practice, and for everyone to test snippets quickly.

http://voyage-editor.herokuapp.com/

Hope it helps